# Azure Dataflow fails with error: Job failed due to reason: Not started

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an azure pipeline with several dataflows and this one consistently fails with this bizarre error:
"Job failed due to reason: Not started"
I have no idea why this is happening and have not seen it addressed anywhere online. Has anyone seen this? How do I get past this?

Comment: I just came across this issue today during work hours. The one thing I knew was different that was likely the culprit was the issue. I had multiple sinks with the same linked resource (a cosmos collection). In my case I was trying to simulate assert failure output since there's a bug I reported where it doesn't work for Cosmos sink. My workaround was to use a bunch of Unions to put those records together and then output the results to one instance of the sink for that cosmos collection. It worked for me.

Comment: I also tried to order the writing of the sinks, but that did not fix it.